# How to determine React Native statusbar height for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native, iphone11

In my React Native app on iOS, I want to make a `<View>` that wraps the status bar. Most places say that it should be `20px` in height, but on the iPhone 11, for example, it seems to be higher than that. I want a solution that fits all devices.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can's set the status bar height, this is something which related to the phone OS. If you would like to extend it, you can just add a View under it with the same color.

In order to solve iPhone 10 or greater issues you need to use [SafeAreaView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview).

"The purpose of SafeAreaView is to render content within the safe area boundaries of a device. It is currently only applicable to iOS devices with iOS version 11 or later"